# Why Custom Toast cancel when user touch the screen?

Tags: java, android, toast

Why Custom Toast cancel when user touch the screen?

I want is The Custom Toast still run even the user touch the screen, and even it set to `Toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);` , The Custom Toast still diseppair when the user touch the screen.

its more like regular Toast its will not diseppair when the user touch the screen.

How to make it possible?